# raster extactextracter function mean with replaced 0

Tags: r, extract, raster, spatial

I have a raster file which I would like to extract by the exact_extract function of the exactextractr library. But in addition to the the normal mean I want to calulate the mean for each of my polygons but befor that I want to replace all those values lower 0 to 0.

I'm not super familiar with functions but I  tried:

```
Mean_condition <- function(value, coverage_fraction) {
 cond_mean <-  mean(if (value < 0 ){value <- 0} else {value}) 
    return(cond_mean)}
  
exact_extract(x, Countries_union, append_cols = c("id", "CountryName"), fun= c("mean", Mean_condition)
```

That gives me the error: Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
Fehler bei der Auswertung des Argumentes 'x' bei der Methodenauswahl für Funktion 'mean': the condition has length > 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That does not work when then length of `value` is larger than one. You could use `ifelse` instead, but in this case `pmax` would be more efficient. The below should "work", and per your request in the comment, also deals with `NA`.

```
Mean_condition <- function(value, coverage_fraction) {
    mean( pmax(0, value), na.rm=TRUE )
}
```

But that ignores argument "coverage_fraction". Shouldn't it be something like this? Note that you cannot simply use `na.rm=TRUE` because there will be NAs in value, but not in coverage_fraction.

```
Mean_condition <- function(value, coverage_fraction) {
    value <- pmax(0, value)
    i <- !is.na(value)
    sum(value[i] * coverage_fraction[i]) / sum(coverage_fraction[i])
}
```

A simple alternative would be to change the input raster (unless it is very large). With SpatRaster `r` you could do

```
x <- clamp(r, 0)
```

And then extract the values from `x`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I really appreciate that good anwer. I additional Question mybe you have an idea. If I run those functions I got much more NA values than compared to those functions given from exactextracter e.g. "mean". Does they assume na.rm =TRUE? so should I include in the mean/ sum functions na.rm = TRUE to obtain similar results? Best

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect that. It seems to me that changing the raster input is the safest approach. Or you should at least compare with that to be sure things work.